Confused about Git merge with multiple branches. How can I merge the changes made in a branch created from an existing Pull Request branch?
I had a project where I had to make some changes.
I created a first Pull Request:

git checkout -b v1

This PR is waiting to be reviewed and approved by my team lead.
Meanwhile, I had to open a second Pull Request for making a different feature change.

git checkout v1

git checkout -b v1.1


I have made commit to both the separate branches, after the initial commits.
Right now, both PRs are pending.
This image explains my project's current branches
I want to know how can I sort this out, once the first PR is approved and merged.
What are the git commands, to be executed in which order. Please help.
Assume I can merge the first PR (v1) directly on Github interface using Squash and Merge button, I don't use terminal to merge the changes.
Thanks for the help!
I have tried researching for the problem.
I came to know about git rebase, but I am not sure what to do and how to run, which commands and in which order and where (terminal or github interface)?

Your second branch should have been created from your main branch. I understand that on your second branch you may need changes from the first branch. In that case, you could have merged the first branch into the second in order to have its changes and keep the branch history.

a) your image does not match your textual description, there is no extra commit in v1 that isn't in v1.1 b) don't use squash merge if you can avoid it c) rebase is the answer

After merging first PR (v1), you won't be able to merge your second PR as it will show that your current branch is 2 commits ahead & 1 commit behind of main.
To fix this problem you need to rebase your second branch v1.1 with main. Use following commands to rebase on your terminal and you'd need to solve the merge conflicts if you get any.
git checkout v1.1

git pull origin main --rebase

solve merge conflicts if there are any on your code editor & run git rebase --continue to continue the rebase. If there are no conflicts, you are good to go.
If you have done any changes commit them.
Now you your current branch is updated with the main branch & you can push to github with this command:
git push origin v1.1

